# How do you call a WCF service from a test runner?

Tags: wcf, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mstest

I am getting into Selenium WebDriver to write black box integration tests. I'm using MSTest (for now) as a test runner. There's a point where I want to call a WCF service to support the work. I get an error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'Abc.AbcService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I realize that calling external services has no business inside a unit test, so I want to emphasize that I'm only using MSTest as a convenient temporary home for *automated ui tests*, which simulate real life situations of someone using the entire application, front-to-back, using a website driver in tandem with web services.

I guess the problem has to do with finding the .config file when the application is the test runner. Or maybe it is a general problem of having a config file for code in a dll that is hosted in process that you don't control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the WCF service from your test project, you can just add a app.config file with the service configuration in you test project. The configuration will be used to configure the services when called (the app.config file will be deployed with your test dll).

Comment: The .config file does get deployed. But it seems that it doesn't use it. I wonder if it depends which process is using the test.dll. I am running it from within Visual Studio.